# javascript search function to search all columns

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a python script that gets a data table and converts it to html format.

How can I make this part of the script search all columns instead of searching two columns? I do have samples from other threads but just not sure how to apply them to my part of the script since I am new to coding.

Below current working code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {{
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i,alltables;
    alltables = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-name=table]");
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  alltables.forEach(function(table){{
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {{
        td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td || td1) {{
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || td1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1  ) {{
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          }} else {{
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }}
        }}       
      }}
  }});
}}
</script>
```

Comment: why double curly braces?

Comment: I had to put them in ipython environment somehow. It wont read single braces otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was able to figure this out below is my answer to my question

```
<script>
function myFunction() {{
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i ,alltables;
alltables = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-name=table]");
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
alltables.forEach(function(table){{
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");

    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {{
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            for(var j=0; j<th.length; j++){{
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];      
        if (td) {{
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1){{
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                break;
            }}
        }}
    }} 
}}     
}})
}}
</script>
```